# What would the periodic table look like in 2 dimensions?

Tags: physics, spacetime-dimensions, alien-geometry

I've read this question [What would the periodic table of a 4-Dimensional universe look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/what-would-the-periodic-table-of-a-4-dimensional-universe-look-like/13095), and I think it answers part of my question about how atomic physics would work, but I'm not sure. Would a 2-dimensional atom have any rotational axis? How would that affect the spin? How many orbitals would be in each energy level? I'm assuming that protons, neutrons, and electrons exist.

I moved this over to Physics.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/449678/what-would-the-periodic-table-look-like-in-2-dimensions

Comment: are you sure that atoms can exist at all in a 2D space?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: `I'm assuming that protons, neutrons, and electrons exist` Not as we would know them. The atom in 2D would literally be the [Neils Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) on paper, not anything like what we know of atomic structure

Comment: Here is a relevant article: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.14360

Comment: I voted to close this because this is a ["Develop my high-concept"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) kind of question. Further more this is not even about **world**building but **physics**building. You may want to post this in the Worldbuilding or Physics SE **chat** and see what that gives. But as a question in the Q&A section, I am sorry but it simply does not fit.

Comment: Well, I can't add an answer because this is closed, but if you still care, this question is covered in _The Planiverse_ by A. K. Dewdney.