# Geography in a universe with 4 spatial dimensions

Tags: geography, geology, spacetime-dimensions, alien-geometry

In [my answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/12993/75) to my own question, [Physical laws for a matter-filled universe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10901/75), I detail the gross physical laws that would shape my four-spatial-dimensional matter filled universe.

Given a slowly expanding four-dimensional universe, where the bulk of it is filled with solid matter, and nexi and streams of energy interpenetrate the bulk and carve out hyperspherical and hypertubular voids that may be filled with liquids, gases and vacuum, what would the geography of this world/universe be like?

In particular, how does having four spatial dimensions change the nature of this world's geography in comparison to three-spatial-dimensional worlds?  Are there any geographical features that occur only in 3D space, or only in 4D space?

How would the dimensional stresses of the expanding universe be relieved in the solid bulk, and what effects would that have on the universe's geography?

This is part of the related series of questions, [What would the periodic table of a 4-Dimensional universe look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/13094/75) and [What would organisms be like in four physical dimensions?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/27568/75).

Comment: Rooms have 6 walls instead of four, I think? (And the walls are three dimensional instead of two dimensional).

Comment: @PyRulez, A hypercube has eight three-dimensional sides.

Comment: [This Cosmos](https://youtu.be/rAAeLNAfSYc) video with Carl Sagan may help you.

Comment: @MontyWild Roof and ceiling aren't walls.

Comment: @PyRulez, a 3d room doesn't necessarily have four walls, and a 4d room doesn't necessarily have 6.  Talking about hypercubes cuts out any potential confusion.

Comment: Not geology related but close: the concept of "curl" only appears in 3 dimensions (as does cross product).  This is interesting because vortices are intrinsically tied to curl, so you would see no 4d vortex equivalent in your geography.

Comment: I doubt your universe would form solid bodies large enough to make the question relevant.  [Minute Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmNXKqeUtJM) has a video about 4D space topology.

Comment: IIRC, this is partially addressed in the novels *Flatland: A Romance In Many Dimensions* by E. Abbot Abbott, and also the tribute-sequel *Flatterland: Like Flatland, Only More So* by Ian Stewart.  Both available on Google Books.

Comment: @Draco18s, That is very interesting, but you seem to have missed the point that this universe is *very* full of matter, on the order of 95%+.  So, with the vacuum/plasma repulsion law, a new particle formed in vacuum is bound to hit something eventually.  The universe is also *mostly* static, though there may be pockets of movement and/or rotation caused by various interactions.  Think of this as a very large collection of interlinked and potentially intersecting 4D tunnels, with a repulsive force pushing everything away from the centres of the tunnels.

Comment: As @CortAmmon mentioned, there are topological features of 3D space that are lost in 4D. Low-dimension spaces are "special" and have a lot of mathematically "nice" properties. 4D and higher have, in a sense, too much flexibility, and are less structured.

Comment: I can't believe no one has ignored the obvious. As third dimensional beings (excluding poor time over here) it is physically impossible for us to envision a fourth dimensional space. We are not wired to comprehend such things, nor can we fully.

Answer (score 2):

There are many physical laws that would be changed simply from going from a 3D to a 4D universe. The first one that comes to mind is that the does not exist a vector cross product in four-dimensional space.

> If one requires only three basic properties of cross-product, properties which >are explained in practically all undergraduate textbooks that discuss vector >analysis, it turns out that a cross product of vectors exist only in 3->dimensional and 7-dimensional Euclidean space.
>
> ### ["Cross products of vectors in higher dimensional Euclidean spaces"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323537?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Just by the nature of this not being usable in the physics of your 4D world, all the rules would change. Vector cross products appear in torque and angular momentum (both of which would be very important in your swirling universe). Because of the strangeness that would ensue, it is practically impossible to guess at how certain geographies would form in this mostly solid universe. The geographies would be complex and  **extremely**  different from that of our 3D world.

Comment: "Just by the nature of this not being usable in the physics of your 4D world, all the rules would change. Vector cross products appear in torque and angular momentum (both of which would be very important in your swirling universe)." - it could be defined in term of tensors or bivectors, derived from rotational symmetry. Witness the definition of angular momentum in 2D, despite the fact that there is no cross product defined for 2D vectors.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Could it? Maybe, I'd would look that up before taking it as fact. However, either way, it would not be a vector cross product that has the same properties or follows the same rules as our cross product. This makes the rest of my answer unchanged; the physics of torque and angular momentum would still be drastically different in 4D.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Saying what the geography *isn't* doesn't say what it *is*.

Comment: @MontyWild: I'm trying to say that it'll be practically impossible to say what it is. Therefore, you should take your best guess, and no one will really say that you're wrong.

Comment: I'd be interested to read that article without having to pay for it or register.  Do you have another link to it?

Comment: @MontyWild You should be able to read it online at the link I provided.

Comment: Ok, I've read it, but since this sort of mathematics isn't my strong point, I'm still not sure just what cross-products have to do with 3D geology, let alone what *not* having them means for my *largely static* 4D universe.  If you could explain in layman's terms, I'd be very interested.

Comment: So, our universe has three spatial dimensions. Thus, the vector cross product is a valid operation on vectors in our universe. One of its main applications is in calculating torque and describing it. (Torque is like a force that causes rotation, calculated given the linear force and it's distance from the axis.) If you take away the cross product's meaning, then torque also loses its meaning (unless you figure out a way to calculate it in 4D). This changes not just geology but the way your hypothetical universe functions at all.

Comment: @Ethan To answer the question, we basically need to know the laws of physics in your world. (Even then, the question will be *extremely* difficult, since it would require relearning physics. I doubt anyone would be able to answer it if you posted a 500 point bounty.)